# Prometheus licenses expiration monitoring

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

It's there a way to add a text file  with licenses dates to be monitored by Prometheus windows exporter.( to be used with alert manager to receive a alert if a program license will expire in 10 days for example).
So I would basically have this license_example.txt with :
""
Visual studio code : 22-01-2024
Windows exporter : 25-02-2025
""
Can he receive file inputs and if so on what format they must be, in order to recognize the dates for example.

Thanks for help and reading all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it is actually [enabled by default](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.textfile.md). Put `*.prom` files in this path `C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\textfile_inputs` and fill them according to the prometheus [metrics exporter documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge). I'd suggest to use a `Gauge` metric with the remaining days until license expiration and a script to update the `*.prom` files regularly. See a sample of the required format [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-format-example).